# wxPython, Runtime and Assertion Error when closing mainframe

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

I have a GUI running some threads, up to now there are only four. 2 of them are running read routing, from the instrument to finishing uploading to SQL. The other two of them are monitoring the data being uploaded to the SQL Data base. When closing the mainframe i get an Runtimeerror, Both of them update the GUI.

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ACAS\PycharmProjects\ACAS\Main\GUI\panels\hygrometer_panel.py", line 42, in run
    wx.PostEvent(self.wxObject, ResultEvent(self.worker.read()))
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type hygrometer has been deleted
```

I've tried in using wx.CallAfter lines. But the error only changed to an assertion error.

```py
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ACAS\PycharmProjects\ACAS\Main\GUI\panels\acquisition_panel.py", line 20, in run
    self.method()
  File "C:\Users\ACAS\PycharmProjects\ACAS\Main\GUI\panels\acquisition_panel.py", line 73, in ccn_status_method
    wx.CallAfter(self.ccn_status.SetLabel, 'RUNNING')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 3254, in CallAfter
    assert app is not None, 'No wx.App created yet'
AssertionError: No wx.App created yet
```

Here some thread approaches.
First

```py
class TestThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, wxObject):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.wxObject = wxObject
        self.worker = workers.hygrometer_worker()
        self.start()  # start the thread

    def run(self):
        """Run Worker Thread."""
        # This is the code executing in the new thread.
        while True:
            wx.PostEvent(self.wxObject, ResultEvent(self.worker.read()))
            time.sleep(1)
```

Second

```py
class TestThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, method):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.method = method
        self.start()  # start the thread

    def run(self):
        """Run Worker Thread."""
        # This is the code executing in the new thread.
        while True:
            self.method()
            time.sleep(1)
```

This sending the method doing all the work,

```py
    def update_display(self):
        data = self.worker.read()
        index = data.index.values[0]
        wx.CallAfter(self.current_ss_value.SetLabel, str(data.at[index, 'Current SS']))
        wx.CallAfter(self.stage_value.SetLabel, str(data.at[index, '1st Stage Mon']))
        wx.CallAfter(self.concentration_value.SetLabel, str(data.at[index, 'CCN Number Conc']))
        wx.CallAfter(self.delta_value.SetLabel, str(data.at[index, 'Delta T']))
        wx.CallAfter(self.cmd_value.SetLabel, str(data.at[index, 'CMD']))
        wx.CallAfter(self.gmd_values.SetLabel, str(data.at[index, 'GMD']))
```

I dont really seem the error. I've tried different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ensure that `self.wxObject` still exists before trying to use it by testing it with an `if`. The widget classes have an `__int__` or `__bool__` that return `False` if the C++ object has already been destroyed.  So, something like this:

```
    if self.wxObject:
        wx.PostEvent(self.wxObject, ...)
```

For the `wx.App` error you can test it too with `wx.GetApp()` and ensuring it is not `None` before using `wx.CallAfter`. Or you can just delay the starting of your worker threads until after the application object has been created.

One more comment about your code: I recommend **not** issuing several `wx.CallAfters` in a row with each one doing an individual UI update. It's much better to move those statements to a new method, and then use `wx.CallAfter` to invoke just that method. It's much more efficient that way, but more importantly it avoids problems stemming from how the event system is implemented and the possibility of some of those CallAfters being executed before an earlier one returns.

Comment: Both solutions came handy, some easy but i could not see it. Thanks. The wx.CallAfter in a row where just me trying to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the possibility to test if the C++ object of the wxPython window still exists by doing

```
    if self.__nonzero__():
        wx.PostEvent(..
```

You can find wxPython documentation here (PyDeadObject Error)
https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html